# Rcpp compiled Attributes not available for call

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

First I know this is probably an Rcpp-Devel function, but when I try to subscribe using Firefox or Chrome, I get an error at my work ethernet that the connection is not secure, so I have to ask here for now.

So I purchased Dirk's book and it is written excellently.

I am getting a similar error here
https://www.mail-archive.com/rcpp-devel%40lists.r-forge.r-project.org/msg08059.html

```
Sage<-testArm(set,labels,contrast,geneSets,var.equal=FALSE)
Calculating comparisons...Error in .Call("sigmaCalc", PACKAGE = "mySage") :    
 "sigmaCalc" not available for .Call() for package "mySage"
```

note, my NameSpace has the useDynLib(mySage), and I can successfully run compileAttributes and R CMD build (in an outside directory) and install the package successfully.

when I try to call one of the RcppExport.R functions, I generate the error

here is one of my Cpp codes

```
//[[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]
#include <RcppArmadillo.h> 
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
 #include <Rcpp.h>
 #include <math.h>
#include <R.h>
using namespace arma;
using namespace Rcpp;
//'calculates the sd and mindof in order , names are assigned in R, as of     now, there is no NA error checking.  not very robust
//' @param SDs standard deviations from geneResults returned by     makeComparison
//' @param DOFs degrees of freedom from geneResults returned by makeComparison
//' @param geneSets a set of genes for enrichment testing
//' @export
//' @return a List with SumSigma and MinDof
//[[Rcpp::export]]
List sigmaCalc( SEXP SDs, SEXP DOFs, SEXP geneSets) {
Rcpp::NumericVector SD(SDs);
Rcpp::NumericVector DOF(DOFs);
Rcpp::List geneSet(geneSets);
 more code ....
```

the comments here get created and export into the R nameSpace properly
here is the RcppExports.R

```
# This file was generated by Rcpp::compileAttributes
# Generator token: 10BE3573-1514-4C36-9D1C-5A225CD40393

#'calculates the sd and mindof in order , names are assigned in R, as of now, there is no NA error checking.  not very robust
#' @param SDs standard deviations from geneResults returned by makeComparison
#' @param DOFs degrees of freedom from geneResults returned by makeComparison
#' @param geneSets a set of genes for enrichment testing
#' @export
#' @return a List with SumSigma and MinDof
 sigmaCalc <- function(SDs, DOFs, geneSets) {
.Call('mySage_sigmaCalc', PACKAGE = 'mySage', SDs, DOFs, geneSets)
}
```

here is the RcppExport.cpp

```
// This file was generated by Rcpp::compileAttributes
// Generator token: 10BE3573-1514-4C36-9D1C-5A225CD40393

#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
#include <Rcpp.h>

using namespace Rcpp;

// sigmaCalc
List sigmaCalc(SEXP SDs, SEXP DOFs, SEXP geneSets);
RcppExport SEXP mySage_sigmaCalc(SEXP SDsSEXP, SEXP DOFsSEXP, SEXP geneSetsSEXP) {
BEGIN_RCPP
Rcpp::RObject __result;
Rcpp::RNGScope __rngScope;
Rcpp::traits::input_parameter< SEXP >::type SDs(SDsSEXP);
Rcpp::traits::input_parameter< SEXP >::type DOFs(DOFsSEXP);
Rcpp::traits::input_parameter< SEXP >::type geneSets(geneSetsSEXP);
__result = Rcpp::wrap(sigmaCalc(SDs, DOFs, geneSets));
return __result;
 END_RCPP
 }
```

I am not sure about several things, are header files required?  the text suggests that rcpp_hello_world.h  is needed, however after reading the RcppExport.cpp  the cpp function declaration is included in the Export.cpp, so I am not sure I need to write declarative header files.  also  networkBMA, wordcloud, and pcaMethods are all Rcpp packages and they don't include headers, so are headers needed for interfacing an API only?

the other thing that may cause this error is that my function parameters are SEXP objects and not Rcpp:NumericVectors.../NumericMatrix ,  should I write the cpp code sigmaCalc to input  Rcpp types, and then ensure that the Export.cpp functions handles the SEXP casting?

thank you.

P.S.  here is my Makevars  in src/

```
## Use the R_HOME indirection to support installations of multiple R version
PKG_LIBS = `$(R_HOME)/bin/Rscript -e "Rcpp:::LdFlags()"` $(LAPACK_LIBS) $(BLAS_LIBS) $(FLIBS)
PKG_CXXFLAGS=`$(R_HOME)/bin/Rscript -e "Rcpp:::CxxFlags()"`
```

I htink the error is that I am input SEXP as input into the cpp funcitons, this is only required when protoyping sourceCpp to go from C++ to R,  when packaging, the RcppExports.cpp is the mediator between the two systmes.

Answer (score 1):

The post is pretty long and it is tricky to see the structure. I recommend you start over and do either one of

- call `Rcpp.package.skeleton()` and study that package, or
- use RStudio to create a package for you, or
- use an example package like [RcppExamples](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RcppExamples/index.html)

Start with these, rebuild them.  Then slowly add your function, run `compileAttributes()` and rebuild/reinstall.

Comment: will do.  I didn't want a downvote for a sparse question.  updates soon.  tyvm

Comment: are header files required if I don't import outside C++ code?